# Compress MySQL rows that are duplicates into a linking PK & FK table?

Tags: mysql

**Problem.**
So I have 3 Tables. these tables exist from parsing Midi Files into the DB. so the relationship is below

File -1-2-Many-> Tracks -1-2-Many-> Messages

So each Midi File can have multiple midi tracks "Tracks" and each of the Tracks can have multiple Messages.

The way I link the File to multiple Tracks is using an FK I also use an FK to link a single Track to each of the Messages within that track.

I have noticed in Messages that a lot of the data is duplicates and the only difference is the track to which they are linked to.

**My Question.**
Is it possible to automatically tell MySQL to find the duplicates in Messages and then only create 1 instance of the row and create a linking table to each track so it will remove duplicates?

**My Aim.**
I want to try and reduce the 900 million rows to as little as possible since I'm only on a laptop and it takes forever to scan.

Thanks.

Comment: You need a *many-to-many* relation between `tracks` and `messages`. But for 900M rows it's going to be a hard job for your system.

Comment: Are messages unique per track and is there a known maximum number of unique messages track can refer to? You can store a list of per-track message hashes in tracks table json field and messages table with hash,message fields.